# Getting "jmeter.sh: 111: ./jmeter: not found" message on running jmeter using docker container

Tags: docker, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Running Docker using below command

```
docker run --env-file enviormentVariables.txt esign_performance_testing:latest env
```

Failing n below code:

```
sh jmeter.sh ${RMI_HOST_DEF} -n -t ./Scripts/Test.jmx -l ./Results/Results_$timestamp.jtl -j ./Log/ScriptLogs_$timestamp.log -e -o ./Report/RunReport_$timestamp -JProfile=1
```

Giving Error

```
"jmeter.sh: 111: ./jmeter: not found"
```

Docker File:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/ubuntu:focal

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=America/New_York





# RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install wget unzip zip -y


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

# Set up the Chrome PPA
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list


# Update the package list and install chrome
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
RUN echo "complete"


# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.19
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix

WORKDIR /app
COPY apache-jmeter-5.4 ./apache-jmeter-5.4

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "a+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "a+x", "./apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/jmeter.sh"]  
RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

[image]

Docker EntryPoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
```

set -e
echo Initializing the Performance Execution
echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"
timestamp=$(date +%s)
echo Performance execution initialization complete
echo Performance execution Started Succesfully for timestamp $timestamp

cd ./apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/

for f in `find . -name '*.sh' -o -regex './s?bin/[^/]+' -o -regex './usr/sbin/[^/]+' -o -regex './usr/lib/[^/]+'` ;do
( cd `dirname $f` && chmod a+x  `basename $f` )
done

ls -l *.sh

StartTime=$(date +"%d-%b-%y-%T")
StartUnixTime=$(date +"%s000")

echo Start time $StartTime
echo Start Unix time $StartUnixTime

RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0

echo eSignLoadTest Execution Started
sh jmeter.sh ${RMI_HOST_DEF} -n -t ./Scripts/eSignLoadTest.jmx -l ./Results/Results_$timestamp.jtl -j ./Log/ScriptLogs_$timestamp.log -e -o ./Report/RunReport_$timestamp -JProfile=1

EndTime=$(date +"%d-%b-%y-%T")
EndUnixTime=$(date +"%s000")

echo Start time $EndTime
echo End Unix time $EndUnixTime

echo Zipping the HTML Dashboard
zip -P Smartsign+ -r ./Report/htmlReport$timestamp.zip ./Report/RunReport_$timestamp

echo eSignLoadTestEmail Execution Started Sending the zip file by email
sh jmeter.sh ${RMI_HOST_DEF} -n -t ./Scripts/eSignLoadTestEmail.jmx -JFolderTStamp=./Report/htmlReport$timestamp.zip -JStartTime=$StartTime -JEndTime=$EndTime  -JSUnixTime=$StartUnixTime -JEUnixTime=$EndUnixTime

echo Run completed Succesfully. Creating Run Reports For -  $timestamp
cd Log
echo Script Log Data for this execution -
cat ScriptLogs_$timestamp.log

mv SummaryReport.jtl SummaryReport_$timestamp.jtl
mv ViewResultsTree.jtl ViewResultsTree_$timestamp.jtl
cd ..
cd ..
echo Report files Created with suffix -  $timestamp
echo  Run completed Successfully

[image]

Comment: Please replace your images with actual code.

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) for an explanation of why screenshots don't count towards meeting [MRE] requirements.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without access to the `esign_performance_testing` image or seeing your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

The error is self-explanatory: `jmeter.sh` wrapper cannot find [`jmeter`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter) script in the current working directory, make sure it's there and the user has [permissions](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-file-permissions-explained) for executing it.

See [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) for JMeter installation instructions.

Comment: Added DockerFile code